# Django field with lambda as default value and unique = True

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.6

I have got basically this model (other fields left out):

```
class GiftBase(models.Model):
    """
        A base class for describing gift type items.

    """
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex, unique=True)
```

When I do

```
./manage.py schemamigration facebookapp --auto
./manage.py migrate facebookapp
```

I get this output

```
Running migrations for facebookapp:
 - Migrating forwards to 0053_auto__add_field_giftbase_uuid__add_field_purchase_uuid.
 > facebookapp:0053_auto__add_field_giftbase_uuid__add_field_purchase_uuid
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "facebookapp_giftbase" ADD COLUMN "uuid" varchar(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT '8de722a747974db3aab4c1fdaa618f16';
The error was: could not create unique index "facebookapp_giftbase_uuid_key"
DETAIL:  Key (uuid)=(8de722a747974db3aab4c1fdaa618f16) is duplicated.
```

From this, I realise that the default value for uuid field is precalculated and used for each new entry and therefore it is not unique to each object. How can I get it to calculate the value for each object individually?

Comment: Can you please share the migration?

Comment: As you can see default value is hardcoded in your migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed. I first created the fields with null=True and unique=False, then I programmatically provided values for uuid fields and then altered the fields to make them unique=True and used create_unique on them.

Here's the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from south.utils import datetime_utils as datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db import models

import uuid


class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding field 'Company.uuid'
        db.add_column(u'facebookapp_company', 'uuid',
                      self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=32, null=True),
                      keep_default=False)

        # Adding field 'GiftBase.uuid'
        db.add_column(u'facebookapp_giftbase', 'uuid',
                      self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=32, null=True),
                      keep_default=False)

        # Adding field 'Purchase.uuid'
        db.add_column(u'facebookapp_purchase', 'uuid',
                      self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=32, null=True),
                      keep_default=False)

        for model in (orm.Company, orm.GiftBase, orm.Purchase):
            for obj in model.objects.all():
                obj.uuid = uuid.uuid4().hex
                obj.save()

        db.alter_column(u'facebookapp_company', 'uuid',
                self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=32, unique=True, null=False))
        db.create_unique(u'facebookapp_company', ['uuid'])

        db.alter_column(u'facebookapp_giftbase', 'uuid',
                self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=32, unique=True, null=False))
        db.create_unique(u'facebookapp_giftbase', ['uuid'])

        db.alter_column(u'facebookapp_purchase', 'uuid',
                self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=32, unique=True, null=False))
        db.create_unique(u'facebookapp_purchase', ['uuid'])


    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting field 'Company.uuid'
        db.delete_column(u'facebookapp_company', 'uuid')

        # Deleting field 'GiftBase.uuid'
        db.delete_column(u'facebookapp_giftbase', 'uuid')

        # Deleting field 'Purchase.uuid'
        db.delete_column(u'facebookapp_purchase', 'uuid')
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
from uuid import uuid4

from django.db.models import Model, CharField


def get_default_uuid():
    return uuid4().hex


class GiftBase(Model):
    """
    A base class for describing gift type items.
    """
    uuid = CharField(max_length=32, default=get_default_uuid, unique=True)
```

Don't forget to check autogenerated migration. If there is still hardcoded value, try to put `get_default_uuid` directly to the migration file and then edit `default`.

If you are adding that column to an already existing table you need to provide values for already existing rows.

South will ask you for a one-off value but as far as I know there is only `datetime` available. If so, you could use `utcnow.strftime` and then run update with `uuid4` as the part of migration.

Also, I would suggest to avoid using lambdas for field options like default and always check autogenerated migrations.

Comment: Didn't notice that you are using `south`. Updated my answer.